# Open Associated File in Electron App by Double Click the File in File Explorer

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm new to electron and have an issue.I want to open file from the explorer by Double Clicking the file in my electron app.I've not idea about how can i do it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add fileassociations to you package.json file. I've provided an example i've used. Also right click the file you want to open and select your app name from the list of apps and select to open through your app

```
"win": {
  "target": [
    "nsis"
  ]
},
"fileAssociations":{
  "ext": "mbmi",
  "name": "Multi Business Model Innovation"
},
"nsis": {
  "oneClick": true,
  "perMachine": true
}
```